# Force UTF-8 encoding in inline CSS

Tags: css, encoding, utf-8

I have inline CSS loading within an element which renders a close (`X`) icon on a popup overlay. When rendered on a page which is not in UTF-8 it is rendered badly with local characters instead.

Code is as follows:

```css
.close{
  position:absolute;
  top:-14px;
  right:-13px;
  cursor:pointer;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #918686;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #575757;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 13px 6px;
  font-family: "Times Roman", times, serif;
}

.close::before{
  content:"\u00D6";
 }
```

Two questions:

1. Is there an HTML equivalent of a close icon (X) that I can use in the CSS content type? And will it be rendered the same way regardless of encoding?
2. Can I force UTF-8 encoding in the inline CSS only for this class? I do not have control over the rest of the page which resides on 3rd party server.
3. Can I use a BASE64 image in the `::before` selector? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "inline CSS"? As you have entire CSS rules with selectors, these can't be inline styles (and further, you can't specify pseudo-elements in inline styles).

Comment: The selectors exist, but the styles are applied after the page is loaded and re-rendered with a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> .close::before{
>   content:"\u00D6";
> }
> ```

The CSS syntax for Unicode characters does **not** include the `u` prefix. The correct syntax is: `content:"\00D6";` or simply `content:"\D6";`. This character notation always refers to a Unicode Codepoint regardless of the character encoding of the (HTML) document that contains it.

**However**, the character `"\00D6"` refers to the Unicode character

- **`Ö`** ([U+00D6 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS](https://codepoints.net/U+00D6))

This is likely to display badly if you expected it to display a cross. Perhaps you meant to use `"\00D7"`:

- **`×`** ([U+00D7 MULTIPLICATION SIGN](https://codepoints.net/U+00D7))

In other words, your code should read:

```css
.close::before {
  content: "\00D7";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set the encoding at the beginning of your css file with `@charset "UTF-8";`

for the base64 image you can use the content property like so:
`content: url("data:image/png;base64,abc...")`

Comment: My problem with the first solution is that I don't really have a srylesheet. I only have inline CSS.

Comment: I have one last question: Is there a close icon in HTML which I can use that would be rendered cross-browser regardless of encoding?

Comment: then I don't think it's possible, it has to know which encoding to apply

Comment: something like `&#10006;` ?

Comment: Yes! Thats it. I am using the hex value of &#10006 - My question is what it would look like on another site without utf-8 encoding....

Comment: that I don't know, I can only say it's commonly supported (the other major encoding, ISO-8859-1, supports it)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `@charset "UTF-8";` on top above `.close{`.

If you are using inline css inside html tag, you cannot use it, as `@charset` is not part of a style rule set.